# Getting two different results when 'cat'ing a file, and 'cat'ing a file into a variable in zsh?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh

The file in question is `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`.

When I cat it, I receive `Full`. But when I do `status="$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)"` and then echo `status`, I receive `1` when I want it to output `Full`. I'm sure I'm just being an idiot and missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably designed for bash. In `zsh` you get 1 for error:

```
zsh: read-only variable: status
```

`status` is a reserved variable. Try `my_status`.

Comment: Yup, you're right. For some reason zsh wasn't printing the error message.